# Why is the transport operator skew-symmetric?

Tags: operator-theory, skew-symmetric-matrices

In the context of [this paper](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.schmeiser/DMS-I.pdf), where
$$
T:=v\cdot\nabla_x-\nabla_xV\cdot\nabla_v
$$
is a transport operator, it is said on page 3, that $T$ is skew-symmetric with respect to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, where
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d}fg\, d\mu,\quad d\mu=d\mu(x,v):=\frac{dvdx}{F(x,v)}.
$$

What does **skew-symmetric** mean here? Does this mean
$$
\langle Tf,f\rangle=0\quad\forall f\in\textrm{dom}(T)\tag{*}?
$$
If yes, I do not see $(*)$:

Let's assume $d=1$ for simplicity, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Tf,f\rangle &= \iint_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}} \left(v\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\frac{dV}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)f\, d\mu\\
&=\iint_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}\frac{v\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f}{F(x,v)}\, dv\, dx-\iint_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}\frac{\frac{dV}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}}{F(x,v)}\, dv\, dx
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that:

$$
\langle T f, g \rangle = -\langle f, T g\rangle
$$

And this can be shown straightforwardly by noting that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} [v f] = v \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left[ \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} f\right] = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$, then integrating each of the terms in the operator by parts. The boundary terms from integrating by parts are zero as a result of the normalization condition that they state:

$$
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d} F \text{d}v  \text{d}x = 1
$$

It is called skew-symmetry because the adjoint of $T$ is $-T$, like how a skew symmetric matrix equal to its negation upon transposing it (i.e. adjoint if the matrix has real values).

Comment: I am not sure if I do understand what I mean: In case $d=1$, I write
$$
\langle T f,g\rangle=\iint \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(vf)g\frac{dv dx}{F(x,v)} - \iint \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}f\right) g\frac{dv dx}{F(x,v)}
$$

Comment: Yes, so, in the first term, you integrate by parts using the x variable. In the second term, you integrate by parts using the v variable. I don't think that F(x, v) should appear inside, right? Perhaps I am mistaken, and in that case I'm not sure how you'd show skew symmetry.

Comment: But I am not sure! Maybe it is not meant as I understand it. They say: The space $L^2(d\mu)$ where $d\mu$, the measure, is defined as $d\mu=d\mu(x,v):=\frac{dv dx}{F(x,v)}$

Comment: Yeah, I see the issue then. I get the suspicion that you'd need to make a change of variables to cancel out $F(x, v)$ with the jacobian determinant, then perhaps the skew symmetry could be obtained with the same procedure I mentioned above.

But yes, I did not notice they had defined the inner product like that!